# Making a MySQL database connection with a stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, database-connection

All the examples of using MySQL stored procedures via PHP show the script making the connection with PHP before calling the procedure. Is it possible to define and use a procedure to make the connection, and return the connection handler to be used by PHP?

Answer (score 0):

A Stored Procedure can have IN, INOUT and OUT parameters, depending on the MySQL version.

```
IN
Passes a value into a procedure.

OUT
Passes a value from a procedure back to the caller.

INOUT
The caller initializes an INOUT parameter, but the procedure can modify the value, and the final value is visible to the caller when the procedure returns.
```

You need a connection to the database to call a stored procedure.. So you can't get a procedure to call back a connection.